# How to get adb logcat to filter ONLY by specific app (package name)

Tags: applications, adb, logging, content-filter

Would like to know how can I get the `adb logcat` of ONLY certain app, and all its errors and messages associated.

I've tried before with `adb logcat -c; adb logcat | grep com.fitbit.FitbitMobile`, but the thing is, it forces a grep on EVERY line, and sometimes there's a crash that involves multiline where needed information gets omitted.

I've tried the command on page [Displaying and filtering with Logcat](https://riptutorial.com/adb/example/14878/displaying-and-filtering-with-logcat), however doesn't work. It just gets everything:

```
adb logcat -c && adb logcat com.fitbit.FitbitMobile:V
```

I've tried also the [filtering option on Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#filteringOutput), but just mutes everything:

```
adb logcat com.fitbit.FitbitMobile:D *:S
```

[Others commands that get the pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735735/adb-shell-logcat-with-package-name) are not useful if the app is not running when I run logcat, and crashes immediately and is relaunched with a different pid.

Any ideas about the proper format?

Comment: There is no official but many third party solutions. I found [`pidcat`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) quite good. You may give it a try.

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks a lot, that worked somehow!

Comment: @IrfanLatif that looks like a good alternative answer, would you post that as a proper answer?

Comment: I think the answer at [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854127/filter-logcat-to-get-only-the-messages-from-my-application-in-android) is ideal.

Comment: @Bink that doesn't work, because debug info can be in multiple lines, only the header will have your.package.name.

Comment: @Smeterlink Hi! Regarding your reply to Irfan Latif, have you tried it and found it's sufficient for you? If yes, feel free to post it as an answer with some details about how you used it :)

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple solution without requiring a third party app.

Just connect to the device using shell: `adb shell`

Then run: `logcat | grep your.package.name`

It will only show lines that contain that package name.

Comment: This does not work, because some information is in multiple lines and only the header includes your.package.name.